# No puedo escribir caractéres especiales en spyder

Tags: python-3.x, caracteres, spyder, conda, anaconda3

Cuando trato de escribir en spyder cualquier carácter especial (`'^....) este no los capta y no los escribe en el editor, por otro lado, si copio una palabra con tilde u otro carácter, si me deja pegarlo en el editor y se puede compilar y ejecutar sin problemas.

Comment: Hola Pablo, podrías decirnos que escribe en lugar de los caracteres, o no escribe nada?.

Comment: No escribe nada, es como si no detectase que se ha pulsado la tecla. He estado probando con todos los caracteres del teclado, y en concreto los que me dan problema son ', `, ", ^ (las comas son para separar). Además cuando utilizo la misma tecla para escribir por ejemplo {} o [] me funciona sin problema.

Comment: Deberías verificar como tienes configurado tu teclado, específicamente la distribución.